# Split the hash-tags from a tweet and then store them and the remaining string in a CSV

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I have a CSV file with thousands of tweets with columns - ID, created date, tweet. I want the output as another CSV file with another column added which must have the tweet's hashtag word in it that is split from the tweet. I need a python script to perform so.
For example,
If i have a tweet as

```
I love #stackoverflow coding #helpful
```

Then i need to store that tweet's hashtag split from the string and stored in another column like below.

```
"I love coding","stackoverflow,helpful"
```

Sample input from CSV

```
"id","created_date","tweet"
"723456719","2015-12-03 15:16:47","I love #stackoverflow coding #helpful"
"723456720","2015-12-03 16:15:47","I love #github coding #useful"
```

The output CSV must look like

```
"id","created_date","tweet","hashtags"
"723456719","2015-12-03 15:16:47","I love coding","stackoverflow,helpful"
"723456720","2015-12-03 16:15:47","I love coding","github,useful"
```

I am new to python, please help me out. Here's the code i tried out. I tried this piece of code from a github page.

```
#import regex
import re

#start process_tweet
def processTweet(tweet):
    # process the tweets

    #Convert to lower case
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    #Convert www.* or https?://* to URL
    tweet = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',tweet)
    #Convert @username to AT_USER
    tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','AT_USER',tweet)
    #Remove additional white spaces
    tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', tweet)
    #Replace #word with word
    tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet)
    #trim
    tweet = tweet.strip('\'"')
    return tweet   
#end

#Read the tweets one by one and process it
fp = open('sample.csv', 'r')
line = fp.readline()

while line:
    processedTweet = processTweet(line)
    print processedTweet
    line = fp.readline()
#end loop
fp.close()
```

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: i will update the question with the code i tried. I am successful in reading the csv file and converting the Hashtag word to normal word, but dont know how to open a writer and save per my question. Thanks for the immediate response @OrangeFlash81

Comment: `with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(processedTweet)`??

Comment: My problem is how to split the hashtag and store it in another column. the above code justs removes the hashtag and displays it along with other contents as a single string. i want split it into two strings - one with hashtag alone and another with remaining content. `processedTweet` does not have the scope there. @ChuckLoganLim. But thanks..

Comment: @Vi_Hari you said in your comment that you are already successful in reading the csv file. And that "dont know how to open a writer and save". I assumed that you already had the data in the proper format. What does the function `processedTweet` return, then?

Comment: it returns the parameter `tweet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DictReader and DictWriter from the csv module to treat each line as a dictionary. This script will work in python 3.

```
import csv
# Open input file for reading and output file for writing.
# It's good practice to use the with open() context manager
with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csv_in, open('results.csv', 'w') as csv_out:
    # The reader will figure out the field names 
    # based on the first line in the file.
    reader = csv.DictReader(
        csv_in
    )
    # We have to tell the writer the fields and their order
    # and which dialect of csv we want. 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csv_out, 
        fieldnames=reader.fieldnames + ['hashtags'],
        dialect=reader.dialect,
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
    )
    # write the header line of the output csv
    writer.writeheader()

    # loop over each line in the csv. The header line is not 
    # part of this loop when using csv.DictReader
    for row in reader:
        # Split the tweet into words using str.split()
        words = row['tweet'].split()

        # If you need to modify this code, you should turn the 
        # following lines into one or two separate functions.
        # This will make debugging and testing easier.

        # Filter and join the words using str.startswith()
        row['tweet'] = ' '.join(
            w for w in words if not w.startswith('#'))

        # Extract the hashtags and remove the initial "#"
        # using string slicing.
        row['hashtags'] = ','.join(
            w[1:] for w in words if w.startswith('#'))

        # write the modified row to the output csv
        writer.writerow(row)
```

If you use python 2.7, you might have to do some modifications to handle unicode input, if that's relevant. It might be as simple as adding this line to the top of your python file.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Comment: thanks... it really helped out.. I have been searching for it nearly three days... even the unicode worked out... Thank u so much @Håken Lid